# $this use another file

Tags: magento-1.9

I Have Doubt I want to use Same `phtml` file in another `phtml` but it won't work Because of `$this`

I want to know Why it's not working and How to use another `phtml`

Comment: $this refer to the current object and in magento's phtml file $this means block class of that phtml file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Use `$this` to refer to the current object.

To use `$this` either you add the `Method` in your current block class or use the same block class.

Comment: I am using this <?php if($this->getCollection()->getSize()): ?> how to find current method

Comment: Can you please give me some example

Comment: check for `getCollection` Method  or check `__construct` Method

Comment: here is example http://php.net/manual/en/ref.classobj.php

Answer (score 3):

Let me simply explain it. Hope you are familiar with Magento's rendering process.

Generally in Magento each template file is associated with a Block class. For instance assume you have below two blocks

```
class Mynamespace_Mymodule_Block_Apple extends Mage_Core_Bock_Template
{

   public function getMyCollection()
   {
        // Some code here
   }

}

______________________________________________________________________


class Mynamespace_Mymodule_Block_Orange extends Mage_Core_Bock_Template
{

   public function getMyCollection()
   {
        // Some code here
   }

}
```

Assume the class `Mynamespace_Mymodule_Block_Apple` associated with a template file named `apple.phtml` whereas the class Mynamespace_Mymodule_Block_Orange is associated with a template file called `orange.phtml.`

Then the keyword `$this` inside `apple.phtml` refers the class object of it's associated block. In our case its `Mynamespace_Mymodule_Block_Apple`

Similarly the keyword `$this` inside `orange.phtml` refers the class object of it's associated block which is `Mynamespace_Mymodule_Block_Orange`

So in your case if you copy the content in `apple.phtml into orange.phtml,` then all the `$this` keywords in new `orange.phtml` file will refers to the class object of `Mynamespace_Mymodule_Block_Orange`. So when you call methods using `$this` it will invoke them from the class `Mynamespace_Mymodule_Block_Orange`

Hope you got it.